Why is using an RF magnetic field equal to the Larmor frequency best for NMR?
I'm working on a lab on NMR and am trying to get a good picture of what is going on.
From what I understand: We take a piece of material and place it in a strong magnetic field $\vec{B_0}$. The magnetic field produces a net magnetic moment in the material by aligning a majority of the spins in the direction of the magnet. We then apply another magnetic field, $\vec{B_1}$, perpendicular to $\vec{B_0}$, in order to rotate the magnetization away from $\hat{B_0}$.
From what I've seen, we end up using $B_1=\beta \cos(wt)$ with $\beta \ll B_0$ and $w=\gamma B_0$ (i.e. Larmor frequency of the material in the presence of $B_0$) where $\gamma$ is the gyromagnetic ratio for the material. However, I haven't really found an explanation as to why we chose this--from what I understand, the purpose of $\vec{B_1}$ is to rotate $\vec{M}$, the magnetization of the material, away from $\hat{B_0}$ to study its free induction decay. Is there an easy way to see why this choice does a good job in achieving this (both in terms of its magnitude in relation to $B_0$ and the fact that it is oscillating rather than anything else)? Id naively expect a larger magnitude $\beta$ to be more effective. Thanks for any help. I would also appreciate any references that might be useful. Thank you.

Your magnetization oscillates due to $\vec{B}_0$ at the Larmor frequency $\gamma B_0$. By applying the perpendicular oscillating field $\vec{B}_1$, you are basically driving an oscillator. A driven oscillator will give a strong response the closer you are to resonance. Strong response here means you will have an easier time driving $\vec{M}$ toward the plane perpendicular to $\vec{B}_0$, where you have the strongest FID signal that you want.
At the quantum level, $\vec{B}_1$ causes energy level transition in the nuclear spins; the transition probability increases as you get closer to resonance.
Next, $\beta\ll B_0$ is required for several reasons. For example, $B_0$ might be so large that using $\beta$ comparable to it will damage your sample. Additionally, there is the Bloch-Siegert shift in the Larmor frequency (Wiki here), which you may also not want.
And guess what, weak driving requires you to be close to resonance to produce a strong response.

p.s.
I study the use of magnetic resonance for qubits. In this context, I find that using too large $\beta$ does not significantly help achieve a faster transition—a waste of resource, so to say. As for the driving frequency, achieving a perfect qubit inversion—i.e. from $\left|0\right\rangle$ to $\left|1\right\rangle$—requires perfect resonance. So there's that.
And here's some reading materials:

Hornak. Basics of NMR. https://www.cis.rit.edu/htbooks/nmr/ [A great starting point.]
Blundell. Magnetism in Condensed Matter. Section 3.2.1.
Coey. Magnetism and Magnetic Materials. Section 9.3.
Griffiths. Introduction to Quantum Mechanics (3rd Ed.). Section 11.1.3. [It discusses a two-level system under a sinusoidal perturbation, which may be a good starting point for you to view the process in a quantum mechanical way]
Vij. Applied Solid State Spectroscopy. Section 1.4.

